# Sorting a vector of tuples needs a reference for the second value?

Tags: sorting, vector, reference, rust, tuples

I have a vector of tuples of integers and want to sort it by the second element of each tuple:

```
fn main() {
    let mut tuple_list2: Vec<(u16, u16)> = vec![(1, 5), (0, 17), (8, 2)];
    tuple_list2.sort_by(|a, b| a.1.cmp(b.1));
}
```

The compiler throws an error because `b.1` is a `u16` and not a reference to one (`&u16`). I can solve this problem by referencing `b.1` instead:

```
fn main() {
    let mut tuple_list2: Vec<(u16, u16)> = vec![(1, 5), (0, 17), (8, 2)];
    tuple_list2.sort_by(|a, b| a.1.cmp(&b.1));
}
```

I don't understand why I have to do this. Especially because I do not need to reference `a.1`, either.

Comment: It might help if you look at the trait where `cmp` is defined: [`Ord::cmp(&self, other: &Self)`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/cmp/trait.Ord.html#tymethod.cmp).

Comment: If you are so inclined, you can call it in “symmetric” fashion like this: `Ord::cmp(&a.1, &b.1)`

Answer (score 32, accepted):

As Aurora0001 already pointed out in the comments, we should have a look at [the function signature of `cmp()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/cmp/trait.Ord.html#tymethod.cmp):

```
fn cmp(&self, other: &Self) -> Ordering
```

We see that both values are taken by reference, so it shouldn't be a surprise that you have to pass `&b.1` to the method instead of `b.1`.

> Especially because I do not need to reference `a.1`, either.

This is the more interesting question ;-)

The simple solution is, that the `.` (dot) operator performs auto-dereferencing as well as auto-borrowing. Let's see it in action:

```
struct Foo;

impl Foo {
    fn takes_value(self) {}
    fn takes_ref(&self) {}
    fn takes_mut_ref(&mut self) {}
}

fn main() {
    let mut a = Foo;

    // all of those work thanks to auto-borrowing
    a.takes_ref();
    a.takes_mut_ref();
    a.takes_value();

    // --------
    let b = Foo;
    let c = &mut b;

    // these work as well
    c.takes_ref();
    c.takes_mut_ref();

    // this one works, *if* the type implements `Copy`
    c.takes_value();
}
```

So the `.` operator helps the programmer and always passes the right kind of `self` parameter.

---

**Note**: the kind of sorting you are doing very common. There is a method even better suited for this task: [`[T]::sort_by_key()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.slice.html#method.sort_by_key). It would look like this:

```
// note: type annotations not required
let mut tuple_list2 = vec![(1, 5), (0, 17), (8, 2)];
tuple_list2.sort_by_key(|k| k.1);
```

Comment: Great answer. While the comment by Aurora0001 certainly helped, it were the details to the dot operator that I really needed to "get" it. Thanks.